# Download ubuntu14.04 It@school

Tags: 14.04, downloads

How to download ubuntu 14.04 It@school iso . Could anybody Please send to me a link to download this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but some sites link to the
KELTRON *Kerala State Electronics Development Corporation Limited (KSEDC)*.

It has [Downloads page](http://keltron.org/keltron_downloads.php) with link to the [It@School Edubuntu 14.04.4 - 64 bit](http://103.10.168.21/IT_School_GNU_Linux_14044_64bit.iso) (the ISO is 3.5 Gb).

Comment: @Madhav I do not know how N0rbert found the link but probably he googled: https://www.google.com/search?q=download+it%40school+ubuntu

Comment: Yes, of course I googled, but some results looks not reliable (they link to Google Drive or other file-share services).